# Xcode Build react native code and images not finding node

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build react native ios release app but I am getting an error because Xcode can't see node binary,

in the ***Build react native code and images*** section in `Xcode`, I am exporting `NODE_BINARY=node` this way:

```js
export EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS="--sourcemap-output $DERIVED_FILE_DIR/main.jsbundle.map"
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

but it didn't work because `Xcode` can't find node binary.

so when I changed `NODE_BINARY` from node to:

```js
export NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/bin/node
```

it works well this way, but I can't export it this way because the testers team have the node bin in another directory.

so I exported a variable in `.zshrc` file called `NODE_CLI` but I don't know how to use it in `Xcode`
for example:

```
export NODE_BINARY=$NODE_CLI
```

or

```
export NODE_BINARY=$($NODE_CLI)
```

or

```
export NODE_BINARY=${NODE_CLI}
```

any suggestions?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

instead of directly passing the node variable, you can leave it to xcode to discern which node you're using by implying it, do this instead:

`export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)`

Found pointers for this on several SO answers and it's given me no issues